# How to Rollback SQL transaction in between a try-catch block in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

I am executing a Submit routine in ASP.Net. The problem is, while debugging the code in try-catch block, if I/user encounters an error, the SQL Transaction never rollbacks.

SQL Server 2008 hangs totally if I break this submit routine in between. I am unable to do Select/Insert operations even from SSMS. At the end, i have to restart SQL Server in order to rollback the transactions.

Code for submit:

```
SqlConnection conn = Db.getConn();
if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();

SqlTransaction trn;
trn = conn.BeginTransaction();

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("", conn);
sqlCmd.Transaction = trn;

try
{
    string query = GetQuery(); // works fine
    sqlCmd.CommandText = query;

    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn,SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, trn))        
        {
            bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("FaYear", "FaYear");
            bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("CostCode", "CostCode");
            bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("TokenNo", "TokenNo");

            bcp.DestinationTableName = "ProcessTokenAddress";
            bcp.WriteToServer(globaltblAddress.DefaultView.ToTable());
        }
    trn.commit();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
   trn.Rollback();
}
```

**NOTE:** Just while writing the code here, i realized i have catched **SqlException** and not **Exception**. Is that what is causing the error? phew?

**IMPORTANT:** Do i need to rollback the transaction in Page_UnLoad or some other event handler which could handle unexpected situations (for eg. user closes the browser while the transaction is in progress, user hits back button etc).

Comment: Here's a best practice, though it won't solve your problem: put the `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection` and `SqlTransaction` into `using` blocks. That way they'll get disposed of regardless of whether an exception occurs.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Can you post an example for my case? I am unable to do it properly.

Comment: Doubt it will solve problem and little time: `using (SqlConnection conn = Db.getConn()){...}`

Answer (score 1):

First, in .Net you shouldn't be maintaining a single open connection which you reuse over and over. The result of this is actually exactly what you're experiencing—in a situation where a connection *should* be closed, it isn't.

Second, connections implement `IDisposable`. This means they should be created, and used, within a `using` statement, or a `try-catch` block with a `finally` that explicitly closes the connection. You can break this rule if you have a class that itself implements `IDisposable` and holds onto the connection for its own lifetime, then closes the connection when it is disposed.

You might be tempted to think that you're increasing efficiency by not opening and closing connections all the time. In fact, you'd be mistaken, because .Net deals with connection pooling for you. The standard practice is for you to pass around *connection strings*, not *open connection objects*. You can wrap a connection string in a class that will return a new connection for you, but you shouldn't maintain open connections. Doing so can lead to errors just such as you have experienced.

So instead, do these things:

1. Use a `using` statement. This will properly clean up your connections after creating and using them.

   ```
   using (SqlConnection conn = Db.getConn()) {
       conn.Open();
       // your code here
   }
   ```
2. The fact that you have to check whether the connection is open or not points to the problem. Don't do this. Instead, change your code in your `Db` class to hand out a *newly-created* connection every time. Then you can be certain that the state will be closed, and you can open it confidently. Alternately, open the connection in your `Db` class, but name your method to indicate the connection will be open such as `GetNewOpenConnection`. (Try to avoid abbreviation in method and class names.)
3. I would recommend that you `throw` the error. While logging it and not throwing it is a possible option, in any context where a user is sitting at a computer expecting a result, simply swallowing the error will not be the correct action, because then how will your later code know that an error occurred and let the user know? Some means of passing the exception information on to the user is necessary. It's better to not handle the exception at all than to swallow it silently.

Finally, a little style note is that `getConn()` does not follow the normal capitalization practices found in the C# community and recommended by Microsoft. Public methods in classes should start with a capital letter: `GetConn()`.